# the error class, interface, enum expected

Tags: java, swing, enums

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JRadioButton A.isSelected{};
private javax.swing.JRadioButton B.isSelected;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton C.isSelected;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton D.isSelected;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton E.isSelected;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton F.isSelected;
private javax.swing.JButton Submit.setEnabled;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup gbnAnswers;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1; //
```

That error message keeps coming up for this piece of code i wrote not sure why

Comment: That error message keeps coming up for  this piece of code i wrote not sure why

Comment: show more of your code

Comment: I'm thinking that "// Variables declaration - do not modify" is an invaluable piece of advice...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expect most of these lines to do, or why you think they should *not* have errors.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm guessing, that you get an error message at "`isSelected{}`", "`isSelected;`" and "`setEnabled;`"

You can't call methods like this, or while you are declaring the variables, as they aren't initialised yet

You should declare the variables first....

```
private javax.swing.JRadioButton A;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton B;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton C;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton D;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton E;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton F;
private javax.swing.JButton Submit;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup gbnAnswers;
```

Then you need to initialise them, with a method context...

```
Submit = JButton(...);
```

Then you can call methods on it...

```
Submit.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: _initialize_ :D, still +1

Comment: @chancea Only if you're American

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there anyway i can email you the whole code so you can take a look at it for me?